# Why did my reputation mysteriously disappear?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-questions

I had 521 reputation when I looked once, then I looked again a few minutes later, and had 516. 5 rep isn't much, but it could conceivably happen with a larger amount. I checked the rep log in my user page, and it showed no change. I suppose this could be caused if I delete a question, but I haven't deleted any of my question. I guess it could have been deleted by a mod, but wouldn't I have been notified if that happened?
How could this have happened? Would I have been notified if a mod deleted my question or answer?